# Left or right align side menu

Tags: html, css, yii2

I have searched through the Internet, but couldn't find any up to date tutorial on, how to create a dynamic left or right side menu in yii2, using kartik's widgets.

I need to change left menu with selected object etc. Every time i try to embed the menu code, it ends up in the centre of the main content and not at the right or left side of the page.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Here is the code for my `sidebar.php`:

```
<?php
use kartik\sidenav\SideNav;
?>
<div class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
    <div class="span-6">
    <?php
echo SideNav::widget([
'type' => SideNav::TYPE_PRIMARY,
'heading' => 'Menu',
'items' => [
    [
        'url' => '#',
        'label' => 'Search',
        'icon' => 'search'
    ],
    [
        'label' => 'Edit',
        'icon' => 'edit',
        'items' => [
            ['label' => 'About', 'icon'=>'info-sign', 'url'=>'#'],
            ['label' => 'Contact', 'icon'=>'phone', 'url'=>'#'],
        ],
    ],
],
]);
?>
    </div>
</div>
```

The usage of it in layouts/main.php

```
<?php $this->render('//layouts/sidebar'); ?>

    <div id="content">
... $content here
```

Comment: Please show the code ...

Comment: codes are same with the kartik's documentations. But he didn't explained if you need to create a layout file and render it in main or how to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I managed to show a sidebar on my pages here is how i did;
created a sidebar.php with content of

```
<?php
use kartik\sidenav\SideNav;
echo SideNav::widget([
    'type' => SideNav::TYPE_PRIMARY,
    'heading' => 'Operations',
    'items' => [
        [
            'url' => '#',
            'label' => 'Search',
            'icon' => 'search'
        ],
        [
            'label' => 'Edit',
            'icon' => 'edit',
            'items' => [
                ['label' => 'About', 'icon'=>'info-sign', 'url'=>'#'],
                ['label' => 'Contact', 'icon'=>'phone', 'url'=>'#'],
            ],
        ],
    ],
]);
```

and then in main.php added the code below just before the content div start

```
    <div id="navBar" class="col-sm-2">
    <?php $this->beginContent('@backend/views/layouts/sidebar.php'); ?>

    <?php $this->endContent(); ?>
</div>
```

if you have any upper navigation bar or header you can use

```
<div class="navbar">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
```

for it but I don't know whether it has affect on this, as I said I am not good at design.

But  I still have no idea how to make it dynamic when I changed the top navigation menu for example.